# Max Planck - what does 'per wavelength' mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, thermal-radiation, wavelength

Planck says

> $$B_\nu(T)=\frac{2hc^2}{λ^5}\,\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{hc/λk_BT}-1}.$$

It's defined as energy emitted per unit volume per wavelength.  I'm not sure if this includes per solid angle, but I really don't care for this question.

I understand that what per wavelength means only partially. For example, If I put λ = 3m in the equation, the energy I get will NOT be emitted at wavelength 3m, but in a range of wavelengths.

Why in a range of wavelengths? - well, This logic comes from the fact that Max Planck also has frequency related equation and it says per frequency. Hence I know it doesn't make sense to say the energy at specific frequency and we say the range. in the frequency equation(without integral or anything, just putting frequency as 10Hz, it would return the energy in the frequency range of 10-11Hz due to SI system where it's 1hz.

So, how is it about per wavelength? if I thought in this case, as we say (per unit time, which corresponds to one sec mostly in SI system),  is it the same here? if λ = 3m, I'm sure this wouldn't give me energy in the wavelength range of 3m->4m even though per wavelength in the SI system is `m`.

So which wavelength range does my example provide when λ = 3m and why?

Comment: *It's defined as energy emitted per unit volume per wavelength.* No, that is *not* the meaning of $B$. (By the way, it should be $B_\lambda$,  not $B_\nu$.) As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) explains, it is “the power emitted from the emitting surface, per unit projected area of emitting surface, per unit solid angle, per spectral unit”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of this quantity like a *density*.  For instance, if you have a mass per unit length $\lambda$, you multiply $\lambda$ by a length $\Delta l$ to get the total mass in that length.  If you have a density $\lambda(x)$ that depends on position, then the amount of mass in the interval $[x_0,x_0+\Delta L]$ is approximately
$$
\lambda(x_0)\Delta L\,,
$$
that is, you need to specify *where* you're evaluating the density and *over what region*.

This is the same, you have a spectral *density*, i.e., something per unit wavelength, so you need to evaluate at a particular wavelength $\lambda_0$ and choose a particular interval $\Delta\lambda$ around that wavelength, and then
$$
B(T,\lambda_0)\Delta\lambda
$$
yields the approximate "amount of stuff" (in this case, power emitted per unit projected surface area per unit solid angle) in the wavelength interval $[\lambda_0,\lambda_0+\Delta\lambda]$.  (To get the exact value, you have to integrate.)

Comment: “if you have a mass per unit length λ” - this is what confuses me. Lets say I got 10kg, but what per unit means then ?

Comment: Are you find with mass per unit *volume*, like a normal mass density?  The density of water is 1 gram per cubic centimeter, and so if have 5 cubic centimeters of water, I have 5 grams of water.  The same thing here, if a mass $m$ is distributed over an object of length $L$, then the linear mass density is $m/L$, which has units of (say) kg/m.  So, I multiply by a length to get the total mass in that length.

Comment: The second problem is the equation I pasted from wikipedia does not include multiplication with ‘dλ’. So if it does not, what is it exactly ? Imagine in my equation, i put 3m as a wavelength. And I get B to be 500. How would you describe this 500 ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze You *don't*.  You interpret it as I've explained it in the post.  Or, alternatively, the number that you get can be interpreted as the amount of stuff (in this case energy per unit volume) in a wavelength interval of *unit length*, i.e., 1 meter (when typical SI units are used).

Comment: in your example, you mentioned kg/m so what you get is you know how much mass(kg) is in 1 meter. Well, then, in the above equation I pasted, if I put λ=3m, then it should give me energy radiated at 1m wavelength ? But this is also wrong. It is a little bit different. 1m here is wrong to say as 1m is another wavelength on the graph

Comment: Well, you just said it. the amount of stuff (in this case energy per unit volume) in a wavelength interval of unit length, i.e., 1 meter (when typical SI units are used). So you said in a wavelength interval of 1meter. So if I  put λ=3m, why should I multiply the result by dλ ? The result already gives me the energy in a unit wavelength and if it is 1m then the result would be from 3m to 4m

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze.  Except that the units don't work out there, which is why I said it can be "interpreted" in that way.  You *always* need to multiply the density by a size (in this case a wavelength range) to get the amount of stuff.  If you just plug in a wavelength, then you are *implicitly* multiplying by 1 m, and you get the approximate amount of stuff in a 1 meter-long interval, but that's only *approximate* (and it's a *very very bad* approximation) because $B$ is a function of wavelength...

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze That's why you multiply by a $d\lambda$ and ensure that $d\lambda$ is very small (nm, to get a reasonable approximation). Otherwise, you really have to integrate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145476/discussion-between-giorgi-lagidze-and-march).

Comment: You mentioned: If you just plug in a wavelength, then you are implicitly multiplying by 1 m, and you get the approximate amount of stuff in a 1 meter-long interval. My question is:
Which 1 meter long interval ? If i plug in wavelength of 3, would the result give me energy radiated in the interval of 3->4m ?

Comment: Hey @march, I asked a new question about this if you got time. I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Ghoster That's fine, but if you read the question, the OP was struggling with the idea of what it means for this quantity to be a quantity *per unit wavelength*, and that's what I was addressing.  (And OP is still struggling with the idea, as evidence by their newer question(s).

Comment: I reversed my downvote to an upvote after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matted of what is used as the integration variable to calculate the total energy:
$$
U=\int B_\nu(T,\nu) d\nu=\int B_\nu(T,\nu) \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}d\lambda=
\int B_\lambda(T,\lambda) d\lambda,$$
where $\nu=c/\lambda$.